# Batch file Compare Registry With Text File

Tags: file, text, batch-file, registry, compare

Is it possible to compare registry with Text file?
I've search about it, doesn't seem possible, I'm new to batch writing.
Like I want to compare is the registry 
HKCU\Software\Random\KeyNameHere
different to text.txt File

Comment: What comprises the text.txt file?

Comment: Do you want to compare multiple values or only one?

Comment: @jeb I want to compare one value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use

`reg query HKCU\Software\Random\KeyNameHere` to get the output of the key to console.

```
@echo off

reg query HKCU\Software\Random\KeyNameHere > one.txt

fc one.txt path\to\text.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

First note that you are comparing oranges and apples, a file is a name and data, while a registry may be several keys and data at the same time.

Then, powershell may help you a lot here, it allows navigating the registry like a drive.

[MSDN link on how to do it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb648598%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)